# Como fazer um SELECT com SUM e DISTINCT?

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso fazer um select no banco usando sum e distinct.
Tentei isso:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `conta_idconta`, SUM(valor) AS ValorTotal FROM contaSaida WHERE conta_empresa_idempresa=1 AND conta_subcategoria_idsubcategoria=4 AND data BETWEEN 2017-03-06 AND 2018-03-06
```

mas me retorna NULL

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Conteúdo da tabela:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Por que não utilizar o **GROUPBY** dessa forma:

```
SELECT 
    conta_idconta, SUM(valor) AS ValorTotal 
FROM 
    contaSaida 
WHERE 
    conta_empresa_idempresa=1 AND conta_subcategoria_idsubcategoria=4 AND data BETWEEN '2017-03-06' AND '2018-03-06'
GROUP BY
    conta_idconta
```

Comment: Tentei usar seu comando acima e não retornou nada!

Comment: Quero que mostre os dados de forma distinta e a soma dos respectivos valores.

Comment: Como não está sendo retornado,há um problema na condição da pesquisa, só vendo o conteúdo da tabela pra saber...

Comment: É preciso saber se há algum dado que corresponda esse filtro (Where). Se realizar o select sem o `DISTINCT` e sem o `SUM` retorna algum valor?

Comment: @PauloR.F.Amorin, segue o print do conteúdo da tabela na descrição. Acabei de postar. Obrigado.

Comment: Eu vi agora que as datas não estavam entre aspas simples, talvez esse link possa explicar melhor [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482908/php-mysql-select-date-range)

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi o que você quis dizer sobre as aspas simples. Rodei seu código sql, com as aspas simples e não funcionou. No link que você me passou, no exemplo, ele deve ter montado o comando no editor, pois quando vc coloca um campo ele coloca em aspas simples, normal.

Comment: @PauloR.F.Amorin, consegui, o problema era a minha query que estava com as datas sem aspas simples. Obrigado.